# Force mapping of java.time.Instant to TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jdbc, timestamp

Is there a simple way to tell (configure in persistence.xml or similar) Hibernate that it should map java.time.Instant and the likes to "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE"? The intention is to avoid having to use `@Column(columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE")` all over the JPA entity implementations and have a sensible default.

Comment: spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=<your-timeZone> put it into application.properties file

Comment: Keep in mind that this is non-standard: JDBC does not define support for `java.time.Instant`, so you will be relying on driver-specific support.

Comment: I do that. However, I'm a bit confused why there is apparently no native UTC timestamp support anywhere (besides storing it as integer). If at least the time zone wouldn't be dropped by default. This is even worse than endian-ness -- without even the need or any argument for it. Just making data useless outside your time zone by default.... what a mess.